# Overload class loading in XStream

Tags: xml, classloader, xstream, netbeans-platform

I'm implementing a save/load in NetBeans platform application. And I'm using XStream to serialize to XML.

But I have a problem with deserialization. When I was using ObjectInputStream, I've reloaded it this way:

```
public class NBSystemClassLoaderObjectInputStream extends ObjectInputStream
{
    public NBSystemClassLoaderObjectInputStream(InputStream in) throws IOException
    {
        super(in);
    }

    @Override
    public Class resolveClass(ObjectStreamClass desc) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
    {
        try
        {
            ClassLoader currentTccl = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
            return currentTccl.loadClass(desc.getName());
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
        return super.resolveClass(desc);
    }
}
```

So it'll use NB Platform features to find a class. How can I overwrite XStream class loading the same way?

Comment: why is there a requirement to do extend ObjectInputstream? I use XStream in combination with the NetBeans platform for a very similar use case without having to do that.

Comment: Ok, it's not necessary to use `ObjectInputstream`, but the question with ClassLoader remains

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XStream has two useful instance methods: getClassLoader and setClassLoader. The last one can be use to supply XStream instance with desired ClassLoader

Comment: In many cases, this is too late. In the current versions of XStream, you can now supply a classloader to Xstream's constructor (just FYI, I know this is a very old question).